# Windows: network interface numbers change upon restart

Tags: windows, networking, routes

I want to add routes to a network and in principle it works fine.
However, the interface numbers keep changing and so I need to adapt the routes after every reboot.

Example:

```
route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 8.8.8.8 METRIC 5 IF 14
```

This works until the interface ID changed from `IF 14` to `IF 15`.
Is it possible to keep the interface numbers fixed, or if not, dynamically retrieve the interface number from the interface name.

Comment: I have a similar issue with hosts that are only accessible over ipv6 link-local addresses. Ideally, I just want to keep their addresses in .ssh/config and not deal with any scripts, but apparently it's not an option on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Powershell?

something like

```js
$nic = Get-NetAdapter | where {$_.Name -like '*Ether*'}

New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "10.0.0.0/8" -InterfaceIndex $nic.ifIndex -NextHop "8.8.8.8" -RouteMetric 5
```

one could make this work using Batch scripting.....
here's a start:

```js
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('netsh int ipv4 show interfaces ^| findstr Ethernet') do (SET VAR=%g)
set /A IF_ID = %VAR:~0,4%
echo %IF_ID%
```

(`Ethernet`, or `*Ether*`, is my way to get the desired NIC. in my case, only its name contains `Ether`)

Note - if you opt for the Batch solution (not recommended..),
when running from a batch file, you must escape the '%' using another '%', in `%g`.